# How to select 4 equally sized result sets from database table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server database table that has a lot of rows. I'm using a program that uses that table as a data source. The program itself doesn't support multi-threading so I have to run multiple instances of the program and for every instance I need to tell what part of the whole base data to process.

I've been using this statement to slice my base data (data from the table) into two equally sized result sets:

```
SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT * 
FROM MyTable 
ORDER BY MyField ASC
```

So this will select the first 50% of the data. Then I'm using the following statement to return another half:

```
SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT * 
FROM MyTable 
ORDER BY MyField DESC
```

But I can't figure out how can I select, let's say, 25% chunks. I tried like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE MyField NOT IN (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT * 
                      FROM MyTable 
                      ORDER BY MyField DESC) 
  AND MyField NOT IN (SELECT TOP 25 PERCENT * 
                      FROM MyTable 
                      ORDER BY MyField ASC) 
ORDER BY MyField ASC
```

So it would return everything else but not first 25% or last 50%. So in other words it would return data between 25% row and 50%. You get the point I'm sure.

I tried this with my local machine (in Visual Studio connected to my SQL database) and it worked well but when I implemented this in a test environment I'm getting the following error

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

I don't really know what that means in this context. And those `SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT` statements works well on test environment too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should look at the `NTILE` window function - it partitions a set of rows into chunks (any number of them - you decide) and allows you to easily pick the one you need:

```
WITH ChunkedData AS
(
    SELECT 
        Chunk = NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY MyField ASC),
        * 
    FROM MyTable 
)
SELECT *
FROM ChunkedData
WHERE Chunk = 1
```

With the `NTILE(4)` window function, you basically get all your rows labelled with a 1, 2, 3 or 4 - 4 almost equal chunks of data. Pick the one you need - works like a charm!

And of course, if you need to, you can use other number of chunks - `NTILE(10)` gives you 10 equally sized chunks - your pick.

Comment: Make sure to pick a total order so that multiple executions of the same query pick the same rows.

Comment: it should be noted that this gives a distributed allocation -- you get every nth row, not the top/middle/bottom nth of your table.

Comment: I'm getting `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'` error. I checked my code many times and it is equal to one that you posted. Any ideas?

Comment: @kivikall sample code on Stack Overflow often is not perfect. Sometimes you have to go one extra mile and fix a small mistake.

Comment: @kivikall: sorry - I had a typo in my code - you need a comma at the end of the `NTILE(..)` line..... (see above)

Comment: @marc_s No worries, It works now, classy! Thank you a thousand

Answer (score 0):

when you are writing condition  like column_name 'in' or 'not in' then subquery should return only one column as a result for comparison.
In your subquery you are returning all columns so it cant compare.. please try below query

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE MyField NOT IN (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT MyField 
                  FROM MyTable 
                  ORDER BY MyField DESC) 
AND MyField NOT IN (SELECT TOP 25 PERCENT MyField 
                  FROM MyTable 
                  ORDER BY MyField ASC) 
ORDER BY MyField ASC
```