# MySQL: Effectively group into equally-sized buckets by data

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table of Players, each player has a score, and now I want to divide all players into levels of equal size, based on their score, so if I have `n` players, level 1 will have the first `n/10` players with the highest score, level 2 will have the next `n/10`, and so on.

I have come up with a query:

```
UPDATE Players SET Level=? WHERE PlayerID IN (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT PlayerID FROM Players ORDER BY Score DESC, PlayerID ASC LIMIT ?,?
    ) AS T1
);
```

Where I run this 10 times, with the first parameter running from 1-10, the second is 0, `n/10`, `2*n/10`, ... and the third is always `n/10`.

This works, but it takes quite a long time. Trying to get a better result, I have created a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempTable (
    IDX INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (IDX)
) ENGINE=MEMORY; 
INSERT INTO TempTable (ID) SELECT PlayerID FROM Players ORDER BY Score DESC, PlayerID ASC;
```

Then I run ten times:

```
UPDATE Players SET Level=? WHERE PlayerID IN (
    SELECT * FROM TempTable WHERE IDX BETWEEN ? AND ?        
);
```

With the appropriate parameters, and finally:

```
DROP TABLE TempTable;
```

However, this runs *even slower*. So is there a more efficient way to do this in MySQL? I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27971082/how-to-select-4-equally-sized-result-sets-from-database-table), but it appears `NTILE` is not available in MySQL.

Note: `Players` have an index on `PlayerID` (Primary key) and on `Score`, although running without index on `Score` doesn't seem to make much of a difference. The reason I sort also by `PlayerID` is so I have well-defined (consistent) behavior in case of ties.

Comment: I've changed your title because partition actually means something similar but not the same as what you describe. Partitioning could have actually work for you but unfortuately your player scores changing

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think of the other meaning of Partition in this context, but I see how this may be confusing.

Comment: The table is expected to be a few thousands records long (2K-10K). As noted - I have index on the primary key (`PlayerID`) and on `Score`, although the second one doesn't seem to have much effect.

Comment: your indexes will not be usefull because you are not querying on primary key. The index on score can be used on sorting but what's being returned is a different field so it has to read both the index and the table so the query planner might decide not to use the index at all. doing an explain on the query will shed more light.

Comment: I would generate a ranking list, and then use integer division to group all players in **one** run. `group = rank DIV 10 + 1`

Comment: You mean something like `SET LEVEL=(IDX/BucketSize)+1` in the case of the temp table? Hmm... I'll try it.

Comment: You should use `DIV` instead of `/` - `SET LEVEL=(IDX DIV BucketSize)+1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a ranking function. This is what I'd use:

```
SELECT PlayerID, 
    score,
    @levelLimit,
    @counter := @counter + 1 AS counter,
    @level := IF(@counter % @levelLimit = 0, @level:= @level + 1, @level) as level
FROM Players,

    (SELECT @counter := 0) a,

    (SELECT @levelLimit := round(count(*)/4 -- number of groups you want to end with
                                 , 0)
     FROM Players) b,

    (SELECT @level := 1) c
ORDER BY Score DESC,
         PlayerID ASC
;
```

To update the table:

```
UPDATE Players join (
    SELECT PlayerID,
       score,
       @levelLimit, @counter := @counter + 1 AS counter, 
       @level := IF(@counter % @levelLimit = 0, @level:= @level + 1, @level) AS level
FROM Players,

    (SELECT @counter := 0) a,

    (SELECT @levelLimit := round(count(*)/4 -- number of clusters
 , 0)
     FROM Players) b,

    (SELECT @level := 1) c
ORDER BY Score DESC,
         PlayerID ASC
) as a on a.PlayerID = Players.PlayerID
    SET Players.level = a.level
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f55f9/3

Comment: @e4c5 - you can wrap it in a subquery. OP is doing that in the first query too.

Comment: I ended up doing something (which I believe is) similar:  `UPDATE Players JOIN (SELECT PlayerID, @r:=@r+1 as RowNum FROM Players, (SELECT @r:=-1) T0) T1 ON Players.PlayerID=T1.PlayerID SET Level = (RowNum DIV ?) + 1;`

Comment: By using a subquery, you can update the table. ( I edited the post)

Comment: This might be the shortest whay: `UPDATE Players
SET Level = ((@rank := @rank + 1) DIV 10) + 1
ORDER BY Score, PlayerID, @rank := -1;` - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d9130

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your query is slow is because of this limit bit at the end:

```
SELECT PlayerID FROM Players ORDER BY Score DESC, PlayerID ASC LIMIT ?,?
```

Without an `offset, limit` you would be doing a table scan in ten steps. With a `offset,limit` You are doing it several times over! Essentially to get the offset the whole set of data has to be sorted and then only can mysql move to the data of interest. My suggestion is to avoid limit clause entire by breaking up the field into levels based on their scores.

For example if you have 10 levels, you could do a simple query to get

```
SELECT max(score), min(score) from ...
```

and then split the fields into 10 equals levels based on the difference of the highest and lovest score. If like stack overflow you have millions of users with a score of one, instead of min you can choose an arbitary number of the lowest bound.

then

```
UPDATE Players SET Level=? WHERE PlayerID IN (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT PlayerID FROM score < level_upper_bound and score > leve_lower bound    ) AS T1
);
```

You would still be doing a table scan in 10 steps, but now there is only one table scan and not 10

Comment: Hmm... I think I'm missing something - how do I make sure the buckets are of equal size? If I partition the score space into 10 equal parts not necessarily all parts will have n/10 results.  

Say I have 150 players with score<10, then 10 each with 20-30, 30-40, ... 60-70. The bucket `Score between 0 and 7` would have much more players than `Score between 63 and 70`. Or am I not understanding how you determine the upper and lower bounds?

Comment: yes, that's right this is not breaking into equal sizes but based on equal width score (histogram)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I need, but thank you for the explanation about the table scans.